# Is there any way to clone a repository to my local machine via Server SSH that is hosted?

Tags: server

I have Server SSH key. Development staging is hosted on that server. I want to know that how can I clone that repository to my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SCP comand :

```
scp -r username@host.com:/path/to/dir local/path
```

or use the [scp software](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to do so

Comment: Yes, I have used WinSCP but downloading time takes too long. Or is there a way to access that repository via server ssh to push any commit changes from my local. When i try to ```git remote -v``` it just show me gitlab repo link. But I cant push to that remote repo even I downloaded that project via server ssh. Please any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

If the Development staging is itself a Git repository, you should be able to clone it on your local workstation with:

```
git clone username@host.com:/path/to/dir
```

From there, you can push back some local commits.